# Automatically import all excel data in a folder (existing and to be added) to Microsoft Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, import

I have a folder of a series of excel files, all of which have a sheet named “summary” that includes one row and 4 columns (number of columns and titles are exactly the same in all excel files). I would like to create a database in Access that imports the information of the sheet “summary” of all the existing files in a single table (appends each excel sheet's information in a row). And later on, when I add a new excel file to that folder, I want its data to be added to the Access database automatically, without further efforts. Is that even possible using Access?

I could do that using excel (Get data from Folder), but it takes too long to update the database when a new file is added to the folder.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use some VBA to loop the folder where the files are saved, check if the file has already been imported, and if not open the file and get the data from the relevant cells. In the table in Access, you will need to have a field to store the file names so that future iterations will know that the file has already been imported. Some VBA code to get you started:

```
Sub sGetExcelDataFromFolder()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim objXL As New Excel.Application
    Dim objXLBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objXLSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsData As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strFile As String
    strFolder = "C:\test\data\"
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rsData = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblExcelData WHERE 1=2;")
    strFile = Dir(strFolder)
    Do
        If Right(strFile, 5) = ".xlsx" Then
            Debug.Print strFile
            If IsNull(DLookup("FileName", "tblExcelData", "FileName='" & strFile & "'")) Then   '   file has not already been imported
                Set objXLBook = objXL.Workbooks.Open(strFolder & strFile)
                Set objXLSheet = objXLBook.Worksheets("Summary")
                With rsData
                    .AddNew
                    !FileName = strFile
                    !F1 = objXLSheet.Cells(1, 1)
                    !F2 = objXLSheet.Cells(1, 2)
                    !F3 = objXLSheet.Cells(1, 3)
                    !F4 = objXLSheet.Cells(1, 4)
                    .Update
                End With
                Set objXLSheet = Nothing
                objXLBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                Set objXLBook = Nothing
            End If
        End If
        strFile = Dir
    Loop Until strFile = ""
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objXLSheet = Nothing
    objXLBook.Close
    Set objXLBook = Nothing
    objXL.Quit
    Set objXL = Nothing
    rsData.Close
    Set rsData = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox "sGetExcelDataFromFolder", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

You can have this code run whenever a command button is clicked (so that the user can determine when the code is re-run), or else you could use a startup form in the database to run this whenever the database is opened.

As more file get added to this folder, you may want to consider using VBA to move processed files to another folder, so that the code doesn't have to check 100s of files to find a new file to import.

Regards,